# Parse string to boolean with default value true

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I have a string and I want to parse it to a boolean value. If it doesn't contain a `true` or `false` string, it should return default value (`true` in my case).

```
"true" -> true
"false" -> false
"something" -> true
```

I looking for Java method or some util (Apache Commons or Guava).

---

I can't use Java method `Boolean.parseBoolean`, because it doesn't have parameter with default value (the default value is always `false`):

```
System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean("true")); // true
System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean("false")); // false
System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean("something")); // false instead of true
```

The same with Apache Commons `BooleanUtils.toBoolean`:

```
System.out.println(BooleanUtils.toBoolean("true")); // true
System.out.println(BooleanUtils.toBoolean("false")); // false
System.out.println(BooleanUtils.toBoolean("something")); // false instead of true
```

---

I can write my own method:

```
private static Boolean toBoolean(String value, boolean defaultValue) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(value))
            .orElse(defaultValue);
}
```

And use it:

```
System.out.println(toBoolean("true", true)); // true
System.out.println(toBoolean("false", true)); // false
System.out.println(toBoolean("something", true)); // true (that's what I want!)
```

However, I expect that method parse to boolean with default value exists in some util or I can do it in easier way (one liner for using in lambda chain).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your method.

Comment: I'm surprised that I have to write this method myself every time. Maybe it's good idea to add it to Apache Commons or Guava?

Comment: Why not just do `!"false".equals(stringToParse)`?

Comment: Because `!"false".equals(stringToParse)` does't say explicitly that default value is `true`. I know that it's working, but using method with named parameter is more clean code.

Comment: boolean value of "somthing" is false if you want to use "clean code", it is better to do a custom methode to change the default behavor of Boolean.parseBoolean

Comment: `"false".equals(stringToParse)?false:true` lmao

Comment: Boolean value of `"something"` is `false` only in `Boolean.parseBoolean`. But generally it is unspecified. It can be `false` (default boolean value in Java), it can be `null` (e.g. `BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject`), `Optional.empty()` (if it returns `Optional`), it can throw an exception or return specified default value - depending on your needs. I need the last one behavior.

Comment: This question should not be closed as opinion based, it's asking a very clear fact-based question about how to accomplish a programming task for which other languages (e.g. Kotlin) have an explicit SDK solution for.

Answer (score 5):

This method does not and should not exist in any standard library, thus, you should write it yourself. There's something like it in Apache, but it defaults to false, and like so much in the apache common libraries, that's a bad method you shouldn't be using. There's something like that in the core libraries too (`Boolean.parseBoolean`), but that also defaults to false and is also a bad method you shouldn't be using. Writing your own method is the right strategy here.

Your implementation is a bit odd:

- It goes out of its way to dance around `null` even though `equals` already does that fine on its own
- It is a trivial utility method and it uses an entire library just to call a trivial utility method contained inside it. This aint javascript - [you dont want a left-pad debacle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) for something this trivial, surely.
- It uses capital-B-boolean even though it cannot actually ever return `null` which is bizarre.

Why not keep it simple?

```
public boolean isFalse(String in) {
    return "false".equals(in);
}

public boolean isTrue(String in) {
    return "true".equals(in);
}
```

These methods:

- Do exactly what you want
- Their name reflects precisely what it does, and even goes a ways into giving the caller a good guess as to what happens if you invoke them with non-`"true"` / `"false"` inputs.
- Are incredibly simple

If you must go with the defaultValue concept, I'd stick to making the code as readable as can be, even at the cost of some length:

```
public boolean toBoolean(String value, boolean defaultValue) {
    if ("true".equals(value)) return true;
    if ("false".equals(value)) return false;
    return defaultValue;
}
```

### Okay, but why should this method not exist in a utilities library?

The general principle of: "If unexpected things happen, just take a wild stab in the dark as to what that means and continue" is a somewhat common mode of operation in languages like PHP and javascript.

Fortunately the java ecosystem doesn't generally adhere to this principle at all - and for that I give the java ecosystem and language a great many kudos, because that principle seems entirely backwards to me.

Let's say there is some method. Given this method's signature and no other information, whatsoever, you give me a bunch of inputs to this method, and ask me to guess what the method should do. If almost any programmer you ask gets every sample input answer correct, then that method is well-named.

There are situations where this is not possible (what it does is so complicated you can't describe it in a pithy method name and therefore doc-reading is required). The point isn't that all methods should be like this, but merely, that if a method *can* be like that, it *should* be.

That leaves corner cases. Everybody can hopefully guess that `toBoolean("true")` returns true, but it gets tricky if I ask what `toBoolean("oui")` does. Surely many french programmers will guess `true`, and so will a few non-french programmers. I posit the following rule: You get an 'out' in the rule that a programmer should be able to guess what a method does based solely on the name and signature: If any input where a programmer has a hard time guessing results in an exception, then that's okay.

The point of exceptions is to serve as a giant red arrow - to turn debugging into a 5 second affair (versus a 7 day wild goose chase. Think about it: I'd rather solve 100 bugs if they all get easily caught by tests and take a minute each, versus a single bug that is hard to test for, affects production and my customers, and takes me a week to solve!). Thus, turn it around: You're the API designer, the caller is your customer. If you (author of the `toBoolean` method) are unsure of what the caller intended for you to do (say, the caller fed you the string `"oui"`), **do not guess**. throw something. OR alternatively ensure that the method signature (name + param types) is going out of its way to be clear about what is going to happen.

It is unfortunate that apache's libraries tend to get this wrong. But note that java's very own `Boolean.parseBoolean` also does this (it does a case-insensitive check, where case-insensitive `"true"` is true and all other strings are false), so perhaps it is a sign of the times - both of them were written well over 2 decades ago and the community's general standards have evolved since then.

Comment: Your method `toBoolean` is better than mine (simpler and doesn't use external libs). I would only change `"true"` with `Boolean.TRUE.toString()` (and the same for `"false"`). But it still my own method.

Comment: You right that Apache Commons method doesn't work predictably (`BooleanUtils.toBoolean("yes")` returns `true`). It should be named something like `toBooleanFromFuzzyWord`. Method with default value can be predictable: `SomeUtils.toBooleanWithDeafult(value, true)` (or only `toBoolean` without suffix `WithDeafult` because second parameter name say about that it is default value).

Comment: Yup. I'd probably name it `guessBoolean` and then document exactly which words it'll 'guess' at. The method name suggests what it does, if you need to know if, say, `oui` is covered, as long as the method name suggests 'hmm, maybe yeah maybe no check the docs', you've done your job as API designer.